# cross_val_predict for H2O

Tags: python, cross-validation, h2o, automl

I'm looking for equivalent functionality to scikit-learn [cross_val_predict](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_predict.html) function within h2o.

I tried to use keep_cross_validation_predictions=True option with autoML, but aml.leader.cross_validation_predictions() returns None.

I followed [link](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/keep_cross_validation_predictions.html) and was able to extract CV predictions for the full training set, but not the only out-of-sample validation set. I'm thinking of using the 5-fold models from checkpoint to do prediction. I have values 0-4 in "fold_column", but the CV numbers in the model names are assigned 1-5. I'm not sure what is the mapping.

Can anyone shed some light?

Thanks!